# DNS server with conditions for resolving

Tags: domain-name-system

How can can I set up a DNS server that will have some conditions before resolving domains?

I mean, before serving the client the resolved address, the server will go through some conditions I'll set up before. For example: geographic location, server load (For example, will get the least loaded server by XML from a monitoring server) etc.

Any lead will help.

Answer (score 2):

Views in BIND for IP-differentiating (geoip-patch for geo-separation also exist)

Can say nothing about another DNSes

Answer (score 0):

I think that PowerDNS supports custom back-ends, maybe it may help (never used it though), but I think you'll have to code your own back-end to use it.

In BIND9 you have **views** that can provide different answers depending on query source IP so it'll do for geo. (BTW, source IP is an IP of recursive DNS server, you never know  IP of the end user, and they not necessary in the same region - see "Google Public DNS").